# Pass dictionary to init method

Tags: swift

I have defined a dictionary like so:

```
var seats = [String: [String:Bool]]()
```

How would I pass seats's type (which is `[String: [String:Bool]]())` to my class's `init` method?

I tried:

```
init(initSeats : [String: [String:Bool]]()) {
    //code
}
```

This does not compile and reports the error:

> Expected ',' separator

Comment: *"did not work"* is not a sufficient problem description. Please [edit] your question and provide a clear and concise description of the actual problem you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function definition should just include the type, not an instance of the type. The correct version would be:

```
init(initSeats : [String: [String:Bool]]) {
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The type is `[String: [String:Bool]]`

So you would use

```
init(initSeats: [String: [String:Bool]]) {
   // your init code
}
```

But if you are going to be using this alot it would be better to [typealias](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID361) it to make it easier to type out and remember.

```
typealias SeatType = [String: [String:Bool]]

var seats = SeatType()

init(initSeats : SeatType) {
    //code
}
```